# bs4Dash: How to disable (remove) dark/light skin switch?

Tags: r, header, shinydashboard, bs4dash

It seems that changing the main background color and also header (navbar) background color in dark mode is not possible. per this link:

- [Not able to change bs4Dash "dark" skin theme background in Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66412147/not-able-to-change-bs4dash-dark-skin-theme-background-in-shiny).

We can always change the sidebar background color in dark (or light using the function for light) mode with this function:

```
bs4dash_sidebar_dark(
    bg = "", 
),
```

However, there is no similar function for header.
Therefore, it would be useful to be able to remove or deactivate the dark/light skin switch from the header.
I could not find any option to remove this toggle switch. If anyone knows how to do that, it would be highly appreciated.
Here is a simple example code:

```
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    title = "Basic Dashboard",
    header = dashboardHeader(),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    controlbar = dashboardControlbar(),
    footer = dashboardFooter(),
    body = dashboardBody()
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {}
)
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set the argument `dark = NULL` in `dashboardPage()`:

```
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dark = NULL, 
    
    title = "Basic Dashboard",
    header = dashboardHeader(),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    controlbar = dashboardControlbar(),
    footer = dashboardFooter(),
    body = dashboardBody()
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {}
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Mwavu. That was easy. Before I ask this question, I tried dark = FLASE which did not do the job. Appreciate your help!

Comment: @FredS. Welcome. Consider accepting the answer to help future users of StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks @Mwavu for informing me about accepting the answers. I was not in habit of accepting any answer to my questions. I learned it today and will practice it going forward.